# How to resolve error Unknown synapse configuration tag in wso2 developer studio

Tags: maven, wso2, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

I created a new sequence in ESB config project.I am using wso2 developer studio 3.8

```
   <sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="TestDBSequence" trace="enable">
   <dbselect>
     <connection>
     <pool>
        <dsName>jdbc/sqlserver</dsName>
     </pool>
  </connection>
      <statement>
        <sql>select si.[Name] as SKU,from [Test] si WHERE NAME = '100000051'</sql>
        <result name="SKU" column="SKU"></result> 
       </statement>
       </dbselect>
    </sequence>
```

But when I am trying to save the sequence there is an error : Unknown synapse configuration tag.

I have the jars files for dbselect but no idea how to add in pom.xml to save it.

Answer (score 0):

Likely the error points to the fact that you are using a non-existing mediator, I think you mean `dblookup`, like this:

```
<dblookup>
      <connection>
         <pool>
            <dsName>jdbc/sqlserver</dsName>
         </pool>
      </connection>
          <statement>
            <sql>select si.[Name] as SKU,from [Test] si WHERE NAME = '100000051'</sql>
            <result name="SKU" column="SKU"></result> 
          </statement>
</dblookup>
```

Comment: Yes Jan I am using Dbselect mediator using below jars.
I searched something for maven and installed the jar in local repository.
Can you help m e in how to add that dependency in project.?



https://github.com/mephist/wso2-esb-dbselect

Comment: Ah I see, so normally it should work with the following steps:
 - Build the .jar with mvn clean package
 - Put the .jar in the repository/components/dropins folder of the WSO2 ESB installation

Comment: So to be clear: The .jar is not linked in the ESB project but it is deployed in the ESB itself to make `dbselect` available